# Why does this query perform so badly in SQL Server 2014 when the CHARINDEX is called in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I changed the title. It has nothing to do with using a UDF. It's solely due to CHARINDEX and a LEFT JOIN.

## Original Question

I had a multiple queries in a command that was running just fine in SQL Server 2005 in about 5 seconds. We recently migrated to SQL Server 2014 and the whole command now takes over 4 minutes to run!

I took it apart piece by piece to find out exactly where it was slowing down. In one query, there is a table with about 80,000 rows that needs to be filtered by a UDF. The UDF does some simple pattern matching using LIKE on a single value. The table is participating in a LEFT JOIN, and the UDF is being called in the WHERE clause. This is apparently a problem for SQL Server 2014. When I move the UDF call inside a derived table and later filter on a column I make from it, it runs fine.

The UDF is actually called twice, but only uses columns from one table. When looking at the execution plan, the Filter operation that runs the UDF is before the Join operation, so it's not like it's doing something silly like running on every row of a cross join before the join condition is applied. I really can't explain why it's performing so badly.

I made a complete example script to expose the issue in a simple way. This is not my real query, other than the body of the UDF being the same, but it contains the same issue.

The script runs the same basic query twice. The first one runs in 80 seconds on my server, and the second one runs in 1/10 of a second!

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON

--Create a table to hold numbers as strings.
IF OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb..#Numbers' ) IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Numbers

CREATE TABLE #Numbers
(
    n varchar(50),
    n2 varchar(50)
)

INSERT #Numbers (n) values (1)
GO

--Double the number of rows in the table. This batch runs 14 times.
INSERT #Numbers 
( 
    n 
)
SELECT 
    CONVERT( int, n ) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Numbers)     
FROM 
    #Numbers
GO 14

--Populate the n2 column
UPDATE #Numbers SET n2 = 'A-' + n
GO

--Drop and create a UDF that uses pattern matching.
IF OBJECT_ID( '[dbo].[udf_Temp_SomePatternMatch]' ) IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Temp_SomePatternMatch]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Temp_SomePatternMatch]
(
    @SerialNumber varchar(50)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsMatch bit

    SET @IsMatch = 
        CASE 
            WHEN 
                CHARINDEX( '-', @SerialNumber ) = 0 
                AND @SerialNumber NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
                AND @SerialNumber NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
                    THEN CAST( 1 AS bit )
            ELSE
                CAST( 0 AS bit )
        END

    RETURN @IsMatch
END
GO

--print an initial timestamp.
PRINT CONVERT( varchar, getdate(), 114 )

--The normal way with UDF calls in the WHERE clause. Runs in 80 seconds on my server.
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    #Numbers Numbers
        LEFT JOIN
    #Numbers AS Numbers2
        ON Numbers2.n2 = Numbers.n
WHERE
    [dbo].[udf_Temp_SomePatternMatch]( Numbers.n ) = 1
    AND [dbo].[udf_Temp_SomePatternMatch]( Numbers.n2 ) = 0


PRINT CONVERT( varchar, getdate(), 114 )

--The "better" way. Runs in 1/10 of a second!
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            n,
            n2,
            [dbo].[udf_Temp_SomePatternMatch]( n ) AS nIsMatch,
            [dbo].[udf_Temp_SomePatternMatch]( n2 ) AS n2IsMatch
        FROM
            #Numbers
    ) Numbers
        LEFT JOIN
    #Numbers AS Numbers2
        ON Numbers2.n2 = Numbers.n
WHERE
    nIsMatch = 1
    AND n2IsMatch = 0

PRINT CONVERT( varchar, getdate(), 114 )

DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Temp_SomePatternMatch]
```

Obviously, in this case, the WHERE clause could just be inside the derived table, but in my real query I need to OR the result with another column from another table, so I simply calculate the value in the derived table and use it as a filter. Once the UDF is in a derived table, it doesn't matter where the WHERE clause is, but running the UDF in the WHERE clause is extremely nonperformant.

Here are the two execution plans in an image:

[image: Execution plans of the two queries in the script.]

## UPDATE:

Here's the execution plan in XML. It also contains Sean's ITVF version from below. It's too big to fit here, so I hosted it on a text upload site.

http://textuploader.com/5dhn6

## UPDATE2:

The UDF itself isn't the issue, nor the LIKE. It's CHARINDEX that's the problem. This query also takes 80 seconds to run, and it's only one call to CHARINDEX:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    #Numbers Numbers
        LEFT JOIN
    #Numbers AS Numbers2
        ON Numbers2.n2 = Numbers.n
WHERE
    CHARINDEX( '-', Numbers.n ) = 0
```

The query duration drops to 1 second if I switch it to a INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, or run the CHARINDEX on the right table of the left join. Nested loops still appears in the execution plan.

Surprisingly, using the same derived table pattern from above (which was fast), is no faster when just using CHARINDEX. This query also takes 80 seconds to run:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            n,
            n2,
            CHARINDEX( '-', n ) AS i
        FROM
            #Numbers
    ) Numbers
        LEFT JOIN
    #Numbers AS Numbers2
        ON Numbers2.n2 = Numbers.n
WHERE
    i = 0
```

Nor is this any faster:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            n,
            n2          
        FROM
            #Numbers
        WHERE
            CHARINDEX( '-', n ) = 0
    ) Numbers
        LEFT JOIN
    #Numbers AS Numbers2
        ON Numbers2.n2 = Numbers.n
```

This one runs in under one second, though, and uses Hash Match instead of Nested Loops:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    #Numbers Numbers
        LEFT JOIN
    #Numbers AS Numbers2
        ON CHARINDEX( '-', Numbers.n ) = 0 AND Numbers2.n2 = Numbers.n
```

Comment: The explanation is rather simple **scalar UDF is executed row by row** (unless it is constant function) when inline code can be optimized by query optimizer

Comment: This is how it should work -- why do you think it would be different.

Comment: Turn that horribly inefficient scalar function into an inline table valued function and you will enjoy greatly increased performance. Honestly, 5 seconds for a query with only 80,000 rows should be a sign it was not performing well in 2005.

Comment: Actually, in this case I do not believe that the generally poor performance of scalar UDF's is the problem.  Rather, from the query plan's it seems clear that the problem is that in the "bad" case, it is choosing to do a nested loop over a large,un-indexed table.  Not good.

Comment: OTOH, what exactly are you looking for in an answer here?  "*Why*" questions about products invariably boil down to things like "*because it just works that way*", or "*because the developers wrote it that way*" or "*it's a bug*", which is probably not what you are really looking for.

Comment: @SeanLange It wasn't 5 seconds for one query. The entire command took 5 seconds to run. It contains many queries, but this was the one that was slowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

I still contest that the culprit is the scalar function. Here is how you can change that scalar function into an inline table valued function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SomePatternMatch]
(
    @SerialNumber varchar(50)
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN

SELECT
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX( '-', @SerialNumber ) = 0 
            AND @SerialNumber NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
            AND @SerialNumber NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
        THEN CAST( 1 AS bit )
    ELSE
        CAST( 0 AS bit )
    END as IsMatch
```

Now to use it is quite simple.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM #Numbers Numbers
LEFT JOIN #Numbers AS Numbers2 ON Numbers2.n2 = Numbers.n
CROSS APPLY dbo.SomePatternMatch(Numbers.n) m1
CROSS APPLY dbo.SomePatternMatch(Numbers.n2) m2
WHERE m1.IsMatch = 1
    AND m2.IsMatch = 0
```

The execution plan from this is much simpler than either of the ones you posted previously and there are none of the nested loops.

Comment: Since the UDF performs acceptably when the OP re-positioned it in a functionally identical query, I don't think that it can bear the blame for this Sean.

Comment: Perhaps not Barry but I would suggest that 5 seconds with 80,000 rows is not what I would consider acceptably in the first place. And learning how to use an itvf is something more people could stand. :) The performance differences could be the result of a number of things since we are talking about moving it from 2005 to 2014.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It's nice to learn something new. A couple of questions: 1) How is this any better? It's still a function that needs to be executed on every row of the table. How is this really any different? 2) Why did you add WITH SCHEMABINDING? The function doesn't reference any schema objects. 3) This version takes 90 seconds to run! If this was fast for you, was my original query also fast for you, too? This execution plan shows table scans and nested loops, just like my original.

Comment: When I ran this with your sample there were no nested loops at all. This article does a good job explaining the differences in your situation. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/08/04/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post.aspx With your sample data this runs nearly instantly, much like all three options because the amount of data is so small.

Comment: You're saying that my example script up above, verbatim, runs very quickly for you? (Never mind my other questions, can you just confirm that my script up above runs very fast for you? Because then I'll escalate this to my DBA.)

Comment: Yes your example above runs quickly on my machine in my test environment. From the sample data the fastest is the ITVF but the other methods do not perform poorly. Can you post the actual execution plan instead of just a picture? It contains a lot of other useful information that the picture just doesn't have.

Comment: @SeanLange Are you running SQL Server 2014 SP1? What's the best way to share an execution plan? The text version?

Comment: Just right click in the Execution Plan tab and "Save Execution Plan As..."

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm that you are on SQL Server 2014? I don't want to tell my DBA it works fine for others if you're on a different version.

Comment: @SeanLange I hate to be a pest, but can you please confirm if you are on SQL Server 2014? As I said, this query runs instantly for me on SQL 2005, so there's definitely a server version involved in my issue. If you aren't on the same server version as me then it's no use to tell my DBA, "It runs fine for this other guy!" Thanks!

Comment: My local is 2008r2 but I have access to 2014. Let me spin that up on there and see what we get.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks. I have a feeling it'll be just as slow for you, which means it's some sort of bug. SQL 2014 has a new query optimization engine, I've learned. I added some other queries under "Update 2" in my question. CHARINDEX with the LEFT JOIN is the sole issue, and the workarounds that worked with the UDF don't work when using CHARINDEX directly.